# All eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix are orthogonal to one another.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, symmetric-matrices

I did part of the proof where the eigenvectors corresponds to distinct eignevalues, where at the conclusion we get (λi - λj)xi'xj = 0 which follows that xi'xj = 0, where λi ≠ λj.

I want to know how can we prove that this statement is true for non-distinct eignvalues too

Comment: It's not${}{}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a mundane example: take the trivially symmetric real matrix 
$$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
All of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consists of eigenvectors for $A$. Of course, for instance 
$$v_1= \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix},\:\:
v_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
are not orthogonal, in spite of belonging to the same eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=1$. Moreover, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, but still not orthogonal.

However, by  Gram-Schmidt, we can obtain an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors.